# jmap -dump:file=./dump.bin 8895

Tags: java, jvm, jmap

```
jmap -dump:file=./dump.bin 8895
```

I have used `jmap` to monitor the heap memory. I ran the `about` command. After that I opened the `dump.bin`. I could see some garbage.

How can i check the heap memory consumed for an specific request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone help on this...:)

Comment: Please change the title to something meaningful.